# Anuglar2 Pipe - Filtering using Property from Component

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I'm having trouble accessing a property in my Component through my Pipe.

heres my pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'unitEquipment'
})
export class UnitEquipmentPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (value == null) {
       return null;
     }
     let resultArray = [];
     for (let item of value) {
       if(item.equip_type === "dagger" && args[0].dagger == true){
         resultArray.push(item);
       }
       if(item.equip_type === "katana" && args[0].katana == true){
         resultArray.push(item);
       }
     }
     return resultArray;
  }

}
```

Heres the object in my Component I'm trying to access in the HTML when i use my filter:

```
  unit = {
    "dagger": true,
    "sword": false,
    "great_sword": false,
    "katana": true
  };
```

Heres the array I'm trying to filter, also inside my Component:

```
  rhandequip = [
    {
      "name": "Hidden Truth",
      "equip_name": "hidden-truth",
      "equip_type": "great_sword"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mursama",
      "equip_name": "mursama",
      "equip_type": "katana"
    },
    {
      "name": "Battle Dagger",
      "equip_name": "battle-dagger",
      "equip_type": "dagger"
    },
    {
      "name": "Boomer",
      "equip_name": "boomer",
      "equip_type": "sword"
    },
    {
      "name": "Broadsword",
      "equip_name": "broadsword",
      "equip_type": "sword"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bronze Knife",
      "equip_name": "bronze-knife",
      "equip_type": "dagger"
    }
  ]
```

And finally the HTML:

```
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rHandSelect" name="emptyRightHand" #righthand (input)="getRHand(righthand.value)">
    <option value="Empty">Empty</option>
    <option *ngFor="let rhand of rhandequip | unitEquipment: 'unit'" value="{{rhand.equip_name}}">{{rhand.name}} &#x25B6; {{rhand.info}}</option>
  </select>
```

Basically when I select a unit, I'm trying to return all the objects in my array with a equip_type that unit has listed as true. The `item.equip_type === "dagger"` and `item.equip_type === "katana"` parts work in my IF statement, however the `args[0].dagger == true` and `&& args[0].katana == true` don't seem to work. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried `'unit'` with and without quotes as well, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving a string to your pipe as arg `unitEquipment: 'unit'`.

It should be `unitEquipment: unit`.

And inside of your pipe, just use it like this `args.dagger`.